# How to use a one to many class in a junction table?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm currently working on an android application using room, with a chinese dictionary where there's a one to many relation between a character and its english definitions.

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName="characters")
data class Character(var mandarin : String) {
    @PrimaryKey
    var charcterId : Int = 0
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "definitions",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Character::class,
            parentColumns = ["character_id"],
            childColumns = ["parent_character_id"]
        )
    ]
)
class Definition(
    var english : String,
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "definition_id")
    var definitionId : Int = 0
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_character_id")
    var parentCharacterId : Int = 0
}
```

I have a class that I use to store a character and its list of definitions:

```kotlin
data class Word (
    @Embedded val character : Character,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "character_id",
        entityColumn = "parent_character_id"
        //,associateBy = Junction(JunctionWordXDefinition::class)
    )
    val definitions : MutableList<Definition>
)
```

My goal is to be able to allow the user to be able to create lists of these words for an activity, and so this will consist of a Many-To-Many relationship between a topic and the Words.

My question is: As android requires classes used in a junction to be either an entity, or a database view, is it possible to use my One-To-Many Word class in the juction table?
Or do I have to modify it to use a junction table?

These are the classes I've created to try and implement this, but I get an error stating Word needs to be an entity or a database view.

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "topics")
data class Topic(
    val title: String = ""
) {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "topic_id")
    var id : Int= 0
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["topic_id", "character_id"])
data class JunctionTopicXWord (
    val topicId : Int,
    val characterId : Int
)
```

```kotlin
data class Lesson(
    @Embedded var topic: Topic,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "topic_id",
        entityColumn = "character_id",
        associateBy = Junction(JunctionTopicXWord::class)
    )
    val words : List<Word>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [Nested Relations in Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships) you can try to use without modifying your entities.

I guess it should be something like that (entity `Word` don't need changes):

```
data class Lesson(
    @Embedded var topic: Topic,
    @Relation(
        entity = Character::class,
        parentColumn = "character_id",
        entityColumn = "character_id",
        associateBy = Junction(JunctionTopicXWord::class)
    )
    val words : List<Word>
)
```